# Break For loop after element found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am searching and selecting a specific user in a popup window. However, when the user is selected, window closes automatically and that break the for loop and give me an error. Looking for a way to break out of both For loop after a user is selected. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
table_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='list']")
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    for col in row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "th"):
        if col.text.startswith("UserTest") :
            col.click()
            break
```

After UserTest selected popup window closes by default. Although, For loop is still running and trying to run next iteration and that throws an error

```
NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: window was already closed
```

Answer (score 4):

What your `break` is currently doing is merely exiting the inner `for` loop, not the outer one.

So what you can do is wrap your entire iteration code in a function and use `return` to exit the whole function.

```py
# <-- snip -->
def loop(rows):
    for row in rows:
        for col in row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "th"):
            if col.text.startswith("UserTest"):
                col.click()
                return
# <-- snip -->
```

Comment: This is also worked but I am inclined to use the one liner provided by Sers. Thanks a ton for answer@aiyan

Answer (score 2):

Your `break` exiting nearest `loop`, and there's one more parent. Most important, no need to use loops to get element by text. You can use xpath below to click on table header with **UserTest** text.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='list']//th[starts-with(.,'UserTest')]").click()
```